# GNU Octave: 1/N Octave Smoothing of actual FFT Data (not the representation of it)

Tags: octave, fft, gnu, smoothing

I would like to smooth an Impulse Response audio file. The FFT of the file shows that it is very spikey. I would like to smooth out the audio file, not just its plot, so that I have a smoother IR file.
I have found [a function](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/55161-1-n-octave-smoothing) that shows the FFT plot smoothed out. How could this smoothing be applied to the actual FFT data and not just to the plot of it?

```
[y,Fs] = audioread('test\test IR.wav');

function x_oct = smoothSpectrum(X,f,Noct)
%SMOOTHSPECTRUM Apply 1/N-octave smoothing to a frequency spectrum
    %% Input checking
    assert(isvector(X), 'smoothSpectrum:invalidX', 'X must be a vector.');
    assert(isvector(f), 'smoothSpectrum:invalidF', 'F must be a vector.');
    assert(isscalar(Noct), 'smoothSpectrum:invalidNoct', 'NOCT must be a scalar.');
    assert(isreal(X), 'smoothSpectrum:invalidX', 'X must be real.');
    assert(all(f>=0), 'smoothSpectrum:invalidF', 'F must contain positive values.');
    assert(Noct>=0, 'smoothSpectrum:invalidNoct', 'NOCT must be greater than or equal to 0.');
    assert(isequal(size(X),size(f)), 'smoothSpectrum:invalidInput', 'X and F must be the same size.');

    %% Smoothing

    % calculates a Gaussian function for each frequency, deriving a
    % bandwidth for that frequency

    x_oct = X; % initial spectrum
    if Noct > 0 % don't bother if no smoothing
        for i = find(f>0,1,'first'):length(f)
            g = gauss_f(f,f(i),Noct);
            x_oct(i) = sum(g.*X); % calculate smoothed spectral coefficient
        end
        % remove undershoot when X is positive
        if all(X>=0)
            x_oct(x_oct<0) = 0;
        end
    end
endfunction

function g = gauss_f(f_x,F,Noct)
% GAUSS_F calculate frequency-domain Gaussian with unity gain
% 
%   G = GAUSS_F(F_X,F,NOCT) calculates a frequency-domain Gaussian function
%   for frequencies F_X, with centre frequency F and bandwidth F/NOCT.

    sigma = (F/Noct)/pi; % standard deviation
    g = exp(-(((f_x-F).^2)./(2.*(sigma^2)))); % Gaussian
    g = g./sum(g); % normalise magnitude

endfunction

% take fft
Y = fft(y);
% keep only meaningful frequencies
NFFT = length(y);
if mod(NFFT,2)==0
    Nout = (NFFT/2)+1;
else
    Nout = (NFFT+1)/2;
end
Y = Y(1:Nout);
f = ((0:Nout-1)'./NFFT).*Fs;
% put into dB
Y = 20*log10(abs(Y)./NFFT);
% smooth
Noct = 12;
Z = smoothSpectrum(Y,f,Noct);
% plot
semilogx(f,Y,'LineWidth',0.7,f,Z,'LineWidth',2.2);
xlim([20,20000])
grid on
```

PS. I have Octave GNU, so I don't have the functions that are available with Matlab Toolboxes.

[Here is the test IR audio file.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rohe4twgueoa28o/test%20IR.wav?dl=0)

[image: FFT with 1/12 Octave Smoothing super-imposed]

Comment: You're unlikely to get good answers for this question, as the question itself is a bit ambiguous, it requires missing data to try out locally, and it's not clear what outcome you'd like. Also, what are the missing matlab functions you're missing? Are you sure you checked octave forge?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Taso! Ok, let me explain more: I have an [IR audio file](https://www.hackaudio.com/digital-signal-processing/echo-effects/impulse-response/) (test IR.wav) which is in essence a filter file which if convoluted with another audio file, will result to the filter of this IR applied to the other audio file. I do an FFT of the IR and as you see there are a lot of spikes in the high frequencies especially, which I want to smooth. I found a function that draws the smoothed plot (in red). But this is for drawing. How can I achieve the same thing but on the actual data of the IR?

Comment: [Image](https://i.ibb.co/mNJBcDm/smoothing.gif). This is the same IR file loaded in a VST plugin and you can see the effect of smoothing. I want this kind of thing but to retain the same amount of information for every octave (1/n, with n=12 for semitones for example). In the picture this does not happen. But the function I found does it.. but it does it for the representation of the data and not to the data itself, so that I could export the smoothed IR. I hope it now makes sense! :)

Comment: It does; but there's still missing data :p  Can you provide a copy of `test IR.wav`? Also, what are the specific matlab functions you're missing? Are you sure you checked octave forge?

Comment: Here is the IR: [test IR.wav](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rohe4twgueoa28o/test%20IR.wav?dl=0). I don't know for sure if I miss a specific Matlab function because I do not know what I need. :P [DSP System Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/referencelist.html?type=block) || [Smoothing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/smoothing.html) || [smooth function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/smooth.html)

Comment: I have tried many functions but the problem is that most smoothing functions are geared toward removing noise and concern time-series data. But in my case I have frequency-series data (because of the FFT) and it's not noise that I am trying to get rid of, but sudden and narrow spikes.

Comment: For example, if my sampling frequency is 44.1KHz and my IR is 4096samples, then it means that I have an FFT resolution (bin size) of nyquist_freq/samples = 22050/4096 = 5.383Hz. Which means that for example the octave 100-200Hz gets represented by 100/5.383 = 18.577 bins, while the octave 10k-5k is represented by 5000/5.383 = 928.85 bins. I want to have uniform representation by 1/n octaves. :)

Comment: Oh, and I must mention (again) that I need to get back the smoothed IR. Because I found functions that can do the smoothing of the plot (like the one I posted in the first post) but I can't get the smoothed IR. If you want I can post several code snippets that I have tried and failed.

Comment: Please don’t add important information to your question in comments. Instead, [edit] your question to add the relevant information.

Comment: @Cris Luengo: I added the link to the file. Should I add something else? If you have the time, could you have a peek at my answer and confirm that the solution I found is correct? Thank you! :)

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: Thanks for checking :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found it. Since the FFT of the audio file (which is real numbers) is symmetric, with the same real part on both sides but opposite imaginary part, I thought of doing this:

- take the FFT, keep the half of it, and apply the smoothing function without converting the magnitudes to dB
- then make a copy of that smoothed FFT, and invert just the imaginary part
- combine the two parts so that I have the same symmetric FFT as I had in the beginning, but now it is smoothed
- apply inverse FFT to this and take the real part and write it to file.

Here is the code:

```
[y,Fs] = audioread('test IR.wav');

function x_oct = smoothSpectrum(X,f,Noct)
    x_oct = X; % initial spectrum
    if Noct > 0 % don't bother if no smoothing
        for i = find(f>0,1,'first'):length(f)
            g = gauss_f(f,f(i),Noct);
            x_oct(i) = sum(g.*X); % calculate smoothed spectral coefficient
        end
        % remove undershoot when X is positive
        if all(X>=0)
            x_oct(x_oct<0) = 0;
        end
    end
endfunction

function g = gauss_f(f_x,F,Noct)
    sigma = (F/Noct)/pi; % standard deviation
    g = exp(-(((f_x-F).^2)./(2.*(sigma^2)))); % Gaussian
    g = g./sum(g); % normalise magnitude
endfunction

% take fft
Y = fft(y);

% keep only meaningful frequencies
NFFT = length(y);
if mod(NFFT,2)==0
    Nout = (NFFT/2)+1;
else
    Nout = (NFFT+1)/2;
end
Y = Y(1:Nout);
f = ((0:Nout-1)'./NFFT).*Fs;

% smooth
Noct = 12;
Z = smoothSpectrum(Y,f,Noct);

% plot
semilogx(f,Y,'LineWidth',0.7,f,Z,'LineWidth',2.2);
xlim([20,20000])
grid on

#Apply the smoothing to the actual data
Zreal = real(Z); # real part
Zimag_neg = Zreal - Z; # opposite of imaginary part
Zneg = Zreal + Zimag_neg; # will be used for the symmetric Z
# Z + its symmetry with same real part but opposite imaginary part
reconstructed = [Z ; Zneg(end-1:-1:2)];
# Take the real part of the inverse FFT
reconstructed = real(ifft(reconstructed));

#Write to file
audiowrite ('smoothIR.wav', reconstructed, Fs, 'BitsPerSample', 24);
```

Seems to work! :) It would be nice if someone more knowledgeable could confirm that the thinking and code are good :)